# CSS Scale Transform on an SVG element with a filter creates blurry result in firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, transform, svg-filters

If SVG element has any filter the vector image in FF not rendered clearly.
See example in FF and in Google Chrome:

`http://jsfiddle.net/7cuwP/1/`

```
<div id="1">
<svg version="1.1" style="width: 150px; height: 50px;" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <g id=":m12-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M-2.4 -9.9 L1.8 -9.9 1.8 11.75 -2.4 11.75 -2.4 -9.9 Z"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m23-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M0 -6.5 Q2 -6.5 3.65 -5.6 5.3 -4.7 6.25 -3.1 7.25 -1.45 7.3 0.75 7.25 2.95 6.25 4.6 5.3 6.25 3.65 7.15 2 8.05 0 8.05 -2 8.05 -3.65 7.15 -5.3 6.25 -6.25 4.6 -7.25 2.95 -7.25 0.75 -7.25 -1.45 -6.25 -3.1 -5.3 -4.7 -3.65 -5.6 -2 -6.5 0 -6.5 M2.25 -1.55 Q1.35 -2.4 0 -2.4 -1.3 -2.4 -2.25 -1.55 -3.1 -0.7 -3.15 0.75 -3.1 2.25 -2.25 3.1 -1.3 3.95 0 3.95 1.35 3.95 2.25 3.1 3.15 2.25 3.15 0.75 3.15 -0.7 2.25 -1.55"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m24-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M2.6 -1.05 L1.35 -2.2 -0.3 -2.6 -2 -2.2 -3.25 -1.05 Q-3.8 -0.3 -3.8 0.7 L-3.8 0.75 Q-3.8 1.75 -3.25 2.5 L-2 3.65 -0.3 4.05 1.35 3.7 2.6 2.55 Q3.1 1.8 3.1 0.7 3.1 -0.35 2.6 -1.05 M0.25 -6.45 L1.75 -5.85 Q2.55 -5.45 3.1 -4.7 L3.1 -6.25 7.25 -6.25 7.25 7.75 3.1 7.75 3.1 6.15 1.85 7.25 0.35 7.85 -1 8.05 Q-2.8 8 -4.4 7.15 -6.05 6.25 -7.05 4.65 -8.1 3 -8.1 0.75 -8.1 -1.55 -7.05 -3.15 -6.05 -4.8 -4.4 -5.65 -2.8 -6.55 -1 -6.55 L0.25 -6.45"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m25-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M-0.4 1.4 Q-1.75 1.45 -2.65 2.3 -3.6 3.2 -3.6 4.75 -3.6 6.3 -2.65 7.25 -1.75 8.15 -0.4 8.15 L1.25 7.7 2.4 6.55 Q2.85 5.75 2.85 4.75 2.85 3.7 2.4 2.95 1.95 2.2 1.2 1.8 0.5 1.4 -0.4 1.4 M1.3 -2 Q2.4 -1.45 2.95 -0.5 L2.95 -9.85 7.1 -9.85 7.1 11.8 2.95 11.8 2.95 10.05 Q2.4 11.05 1.3 11.55 0.2 12.1 -1.15 12.1 -3 12.1 -4.5 11.2 -6.05 10.3 -7 8.7 -7.9 7.05 -7.95 4.85 -7.9 2.55 -7 0.95 -6.05 -0.7 -4.5 -1.6 -3 -2.5 -1.15 -2.5 L1.3 -2"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m26-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M1.8 -2.8 L1.8 11.2 -2.35 11.2 -2.35 -2.8 1.8 -2.8 M1.55 -9.75 Q2.25 -9.05 2.3 -8 2.25 -6.95 1.55 -6.25 0.8 -5.55 -0.25 -5.55 -1.35 -5.55 -2.1 -6.25 -2.85 -6.95 -2.85 -8 -2.85 -9.05 -2.1 -9.75 -1.35 -10.4 -0.25 -10.45 0.8 -10.4 1.55 -9.75"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m27-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M1.35 -6.45 Q3.75 -6.45 5.1 -5 6.45 -3.5 6.5 -0.55 L6.5 7.85 5.65 7.85 4.4 7.85 3.15 7.85 2.3 7.85 2.3 0.4 Q2.3 -1.05 1.6 -1.7 0.95 -2.4 -0.15 -2.4 -1.25 -2.45 -1.95 -1.8 -2.7 -1.15 -2.7 0.45 L-2.7 7.85 -6.9 7.85 -6.9 -6.15 -2.7 -6.15 -2.7 -4.15 Q-2.1 -5.2 -1 -5.8 0.1 -6.45 1.35 -6.45 Z"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m28-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M1.4 -9.75 Q2.55 -9.25 3.1 -8.25 L3.1 -10 7.15 -10 7.15 2.05 Q7.15 6.55 5.05 8.8 3 11 -0.75 11 -3.1 10.95 -4.9 9.8 -6.75 8.65 -7.65 6.65 L-5.95 5.8 -4.3 5 Q-4.05 5.65 -3.45 6.15 L-2.2 6.95 -0.75 7.25 Q0.85 7.2 1.7 6.55 2.6 5.9 2.9 4.8 3.2 3.7 3.1 2.25 L2.1 3.35 Q1.45 3.8 0.65 4.05 L-1.1 4.3 Q-2.9 4.3 -4.5 3.4 -6.05 2.5 -7.05 0.9 -8.05 -0.75 -8.05 -2.95 -8.05 -5.25 -7.05 -6.85 -6.05 -8.5 -4.5 -9.4 -2.9 -10.3 -1.1 -10.3 0.25 -10.3 1.4 -9.75 M3 -3.05 Q3 -4.1 2.55 -4.85 L1.3 -5.95 Q0.5 -6.35 -0.35 -6.35 L-2 -5.95 -3.25 -4.8 Q-3.7 -4.05 -3.7 -3.05 -3.7 -2 -3.25 -1.2 -2.8 -0.45 -2 -0.05 L-0.35 0.4 1.3 -0.05 2.5 -1.25 Q3 -2 3 -3.05"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <filter id="18t4a8dd8-2">
      <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feFuncA type="linear" intercept="0" slope="1"/>
        <feFuncR type="linear" intercept="1" slope="0"/>
        <feFuncG type="linear" intercept="0" slope="1"/>
        <feFuncB type="linear" intercept="1" slope="0"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 50 20)" filter="url(#18t4a8dd8-2)">
      <g>
        <use id="s29d1m12" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m12-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -29.1 -1.25)"></use>
        <use id="s29d2m23" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m23-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -17 2.7)"></use>
        <use id="s29d3m24" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m24-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(0.9962 -0.0839 0.0781 0.9273 0.55 0.2)"></use>
        <use id="s29d4m25" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m25-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(0.9998 0.0179 -0.0179 0.9998 18.75 -2)"></use>
        <use id="s29d5m26" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m26-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 32 -0.65)"></use>
        <use id="s29d6m27" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m27-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 44.6 2.65)"></use>
        <use id="s29d7m28" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m28-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 61.95 6.45)"></use>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>

<div id="2" style="-webkit-transform: matrix(2,0,0,2,400,50); transform: matrix(2,0,0,2,400,50);">
<svg version="1.1" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <g id=":m12-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M-2.4 -9.9 L1.8 -9.9 1.8 11.75 -2.4 11.75 -2.4 -9.9 Z"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m23-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M0 -6.5 Q2 -6.5 3.65 -5.6 5.3 -4.7 6.25 -3.1 7.25 -1.45 7.3 0.75 7.25 2.95 6.25 4.6 5.3 6.25 3.65 7.15 2 8.05 0 8.05 -2 8.05 -3.65 7.15 -5.3 6.25 -6.25 4.6 -7.25 2.95 -7.25 0.75 -7.25 -1.45 -6.25 -3.1 -5.3 -4.7 -3.65 -5.6 -2 -6.5 0 -6.5 M2.25 -1.55 Q1.35 -2.4 0 -2.4 -1.3 -2.4 -2.25 -1.55 -3.1 -0.7 -3.15 0.75 -3.1 2.25 -2.25 3.1 -1.3 3.95 0 3.95 1.35 3.95 2.25 3.1 3.15 2.25 3.15 0.75 3.15 -0.7 2.25 -1.55"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m24-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M2.6 -1.05 L1.35 -2.2 -0.3 -2.6 -2 -2.2 -3.25 -1.05 Q-3.8 -0.3 -3.8 0.7 L-3.8 0.75 Q-3.8 1.75 -3.25 2.5 L-2 3.65 -0.3 4.05 1.35 3.7 2.6 2.55 Q3.1 1.8 3.1 0.7 3.1 -0.35 2.6 -1.05 M0.25 -6.45 L1.75 -5.85 Q2.55 -5.45 3.1 -4.7 L3.1 -6.25 7.25 -6.25 7.25 7.75 3.1 7.75 3.1 6.15 1.85 7.25 0.35 7.85 -1 8.05 Q-2.8 8 -4.4 7.15 -6.05 6.25 -7.05 4.65 -8.1 3 -8.1 0.75 -8.1 -1.55 -7.05 -3.15 -6.05 -4.8 -4.4 -5.65 -2.8 -6.55 -1 -6.55 L0.25 -6.45"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m25-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M-0.4 1.4 Q-1.75 1.45 -2.65 2.3 -3.6 3.2 -3.6 4.75 -3.6 6.3 -2.65 7.25 -1.75 8.15 -0.4 8.15 L1.25 7.7 2.4 6.55 Q2.85 5.75 2.85 4.75 2.85 3.7 2.4 2.95 1.95 2.2 1.2 1.8 0.5 1.4 -0.4 1.4 M1.3 -2 Q2.4 -1.45 2.95 -0.5 L2.95 -9.85 7.1 -9.85 7.1 11.8 2.95 11.8 2.95 10.05 Q2.4 11.05 1.3 11.55 0.2 12.1 -1.15 12.1 -3 12.1 -4.5 11.2 -6.05 10.3 -7 8.7 -7.9 7.05 -7.95 4.85 -7.9 2.55 -7 0.95 -6.05 -0.7 -4.5 -1.6 -3 -2.5 -1.15 -2.5 L1.3 -2"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m26-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M1.8 -2.8 L1.8 11.2 -2.35 11.2 -2.35 -2.8 1.8 -2.8 M1.55 -9.75 Q2.25 -9.05 2.3 -8 2.25 -6.95 1.55 -6.25 0.8 -5.55 -0.25 -5.55 -1.35 -5.55 -2.1 -6.25 -2.85 -6.95 -2.85 -8 -2.85 -9.05 -2.1 -9.75 -1.35 -10.4 -0.25 -10.45 0.8 -10.4 1.55 -9.75"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m27-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M1.35 -6.45 Q3.75 -6.45 5.1 -5 6.45 -3.5 6.5 -0.55 L6.5 7.85 5.65 7.85 4.4 7.85 3.15 7.85 2.3 7.85 2.3 0.4 Q2.3 -1.05 1.6 -1.7 0.95 -2.4 -0.15 -2.4 -1.25 -2.45 -1.95 -1.8 -2.7 -1.15 -2.7 0.45 L-2.7 7.85 -6.9 7.85 -6.9 -6.15 -2.7 -6.15 -2.7 -4.15 Q-2.1 -5.2 -1 -5.8 0.1 -6.45 1.35 -6.45 Z"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m28-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M1.4 -9.75 Q2.55 -9.25 3.1 -8.25 L3.1 -10 7.15 -10 7.15 2.05 Q7.15 6.55 5.05 8.8 3 11 -0.75 11 -3.1 10.95 -4.9 9.8 -6.75 8.65 -7.65 6.65 L-5.95 5.8 -4.3 5 Q-4.05 5.65 -3.45 6.15 L-2.2 6.95 -0.75 7.25 Q0.85 7.2 1.7 6.55 2.6 5.9 2.9 4.8 3.2 3.7 3.1 2.25 L2.1 3.35 Q1.45 3.8 0.65 4.05 L-1.1 4.3 Q-2.9 4.3 -4.5 3.4 -6.05 2.5 -7.05 0.9 -8.05 -0.75 -8.05 -2.95 -8.05 -5.25 -7.05 -6.85 -6.05 -8.5 -4.5 -9.4 -2.9 -10.3 -1.1 -10.3 0.25 -10.3 1.4 -9.75 M3 -3.05 Q3 -4.1 2.55 -4.85 L1.3 -5.95 Q0.5 -6.35 -0.35 -6.35 L-2 -5.95 -3.25 -4.8 Q-3.7 -4.05 -3.7 -3.05 -3.7 -2 -3.25 -1.2 -2.8 -0.45 -2 -0.05 L-0.35 0.4 1.3 -0.05 2.5 -1.25 Q3 -2 3 -3.05"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <filter id="18t4a8dd8-2">
      <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feFuncA type="linear" intercept="0" slope="1"/>
        <feFuncR type="linear" intercept="1" slope="0"/>
        <feFuncG type="linear" intercept="0" slope="1"/>
        <feFuncB type="linear" intercept="1" slope="0"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 50 20)" filter="url(#18t4a8dd8-2)">
      <g>
        <use id="s29d1m12" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m12-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -29.1 -1.25)"></use>
        <use id="s29d2m23" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m23-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -17 2.7)"></use>
        <use id="s29d3m24" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m24-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(0.9962 -0.0839 0.0781 0.9273 0.55 0.2)"></use>
        <use id="s29d4m25" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m25-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(0.9998 0.0179 -0.0179 0.9998 18.75 -2)"></use>
        <use id="s29d5m26" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m26-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 32 -0.65)"></use>
        <use id="s29d6m27" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m27-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 44.6 2.65)"></use>
        <use id="s29d7m28" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m28-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 61.95 6.45)"></use>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 50 50)">
      <g>
        <use id="s29d1m12" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m12-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -29.1 -1.25)"></use>
        <use id="s29d2m23" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m23-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 -17 2.7)"></use>
        <use id="s29d3m24" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m24-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(0.9962 -0.0839 0.0781 0.9273 0.55 0.2)"></use>
        <use id="s29d4m25" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m25-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(0.9998 0.0179 -0.0179 0.9998 18.75 -2)"></use>
        <use id="s29d5m26" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m26-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 32 -0.65)"></use>
        <use id="s29d6m27" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m27-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 44.6 2.65)"></use>
        <use id="s29d7m28" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#:m28-18svjv0b7" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 61.95 6.45)"></use>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

- 1-st element has filter and no css-transforms
- 2-nd element has filter and css-transform (scale and translate)
- 3-rd element has no filter and has css-transform (scale and translate)

How fix this bug in FF?

PS: This behavior not depend on css-transforms, its made just for an example.

Answer (score 1):

SVG Filters convert vector graphics to bitmaps. When you apply a scale transform higher in the nesting hierarchy, you're going to see the result as if a bitmap is scaled up - hence the blurriness

Fix this by scaling the SVG path with an SVG transform before, or at the same time as you apply the filter.

In this case, remove the CSS transform scale which is applied to the div wrapper, and adjust the transform that's on the same element as the filter to scale the element without the blurry bitmapped result.

Something like the following:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HbzhK?editors=100

```
<div id="2" >
<svg version="1.1" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <g id=":m12-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M-2.4 -9.9 L1.8 -9.9 1.8 11.75 -2.4 11.75 -2.4 -9.9 Z"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m23-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M0 -6.5 Q2 -6.5 3.65 -5.6 5.3 -4.7 6.25 -3.1 7.25 -1.45 7.3 0.75 7.25 2.95 6.25 4.6 5.3 6.25 3.65 7.15 2 8.05 0 8.05 -2 8.05 -3.65 7.15 -5.3 6.25 -6.25 4.6 -7.25 2.95 -7.25 0.75 -7.25 -1.45 -6.25 -3.1 -5.3 -4.7 -3.65 -5.6 -2 -6.5 0 -6.5 M2.25 -1.55 Q1.35 -2.4 0 -2.4 -1.3 -2.4 -2.25 -1.55 -3.1 -0.7 -3.15 0.75 -3.1 2.25 -2.25 3.1 -1.3 3.95 0 3.95 1.35 3.95 2.25 3.1 3.15 2.25 3.15 0.75 3.15 -0.7 2.25 -1.55"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m24-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M2.6 -1.05 L1.35 -2.2 -0.3 -2.6 -2 -2.2 -3.25 -1.05 Q-3.8 -0.3 -3.8 0.7 L-3.8 0.75 Q-3.8 1.75 -3.25 2.5 L-2 3.65 -0.3 4.05 1.35 3.7 2.6 2.55 Q3.1 1.8 3.1 0.7 3.1 -0.35 2.6 -1.05 M0.25 -6.45 L1.75 -5.85 Q2.55 -5.45 3.1 -4.7 L3.1 -6.25 7.25 -6.25 7.25 7.75 3.1 7.75 3.1 6.15 1.85 7.25 0.35 7.85 -1 8.05 Q-2.8 8 -4.4 7.15 -6.05 6.25 -7.05 4.65 -8.1 3 -8.1 0.75 -8.1 -1.55 -7.05 -3.15 -6.05 -4.8 -4.4 -5.65 -2.8 -6.55 -1 -6.55 L0.25 -6.45"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m25-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M-0.4 1.4 Q-1.75 1.45 -2.65 2.3 -3.6 3.2 -3.6 4.75 -3.6 6.3 -2.65 7.25 -1.75 8.15 -0.4 8.15 L1.25 7.7 2.4 6.55 Q2.85 5.75 2.85 4.75 2.85 3.7 2.4 2.95 1.95 2.2 1.2 1.8 0.5 1.4 -0.4 1.4 M1.3 -2 Q2.4 -1.45 2.95 -0.5 L2.95 -9.85 7.1 -9.85 7.1 11.8 2.95 11.8 2.95 10.05 Q2.4 11.05 1.3 11.55 0.2 12.1 -1.15 12.1 -3 12.1 -4.5 11.2 -6.05 10.3 -7 8.7 -7.9 7.05 -7.95 4.85 -7.9 2.55 -7 0.95 -6.05 -0.7 -4.5 -1.6 -3 -2.5 -1.15 -2.5 L1.3 -2"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m26-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M1.8 -2.8 L1.8 11.2 -2.35 11.2 -2.35 -2.8 1.8 -2.8 M1.55 -9.75 Q2.25 -9.05 2.3 -8 2.25 -6.95 1.55 -6.25 0.8 -5.55 -0.25 -5.55 -1.35 -5.55 -2.1 -6.25 -2.85 -6.95 -2.85 -8 -2.85 -9.05 -2.1 -9.75 -1.35 -10.4 -0.25 -10.45 0.8 -10.4 1.55 -9.75"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m27-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M1.35 -6.45 Q3.75 -6.45 5.1 -5 6.45 -3.5 6.5 -0.55 L6.5 7.85 5.65 7.85 4.4 7.85 3.15 7.85 2.3 7.85 2.3 0.4 Q2.3 -1.05 1.6 -1.7 0.95 -2.4 -0.15 -2.4 -1.25 -2.45 -1.95 -1.8 -2.7 -1.15 -2.7 0.45 L-2.7 7.85 -6.9 7.85 -6.9 -6.15 -2.7 -6.15 -2.7 -4.15 Q-2.1 -5.2 -1 -5.8 0.1 -6.45 1.35 -6.45 Z"/>
    </g>
    <g id=":m28-18svjv0b7">
      <path stroke="none" fill="rgb(255,0,255)" d="M1.4 -9.75 Q2.55 -9.25 3.1 -8.25 L3.1 -10 7.15 -10 7.15 2.05 Q7.15 6.55 5.05 8.8 3 11 -0.75 11 -3.1 10.95 -4.9 9.8 -6.75 8.65 -7.65 6.65 L-5.95 5.8 -4.3 5 Q-4.05 5.65 -3.45 6.15 L-2.2 6.95 -0.75 7.25 Q0.85 7.2 1.7 6.55 2.6 5.9 2.9 4.8 3.2 3.7 3.1 2.25 L2.1 3.35 Q1.45 3.8 0.65 4.05 L-1.1 4.3 Q-2.9 4.3 -4.5 3.4 -6.05 2.5 -7.05 0.9 -8.05 -0.75 -8.05 -2.95 -8.05 -5.25 -7.05 -6.85 -6.05 -8.5 -4.5 -9.4 -2.9 -10.3 -1.1 -10.3 0.25 -10.3 1.4 -9.75 M3 -3.05 Q3 -4.1 2.55 -4.85 L1.3 -5.95 Q0.5 -6.35 -0.35 -6.35 L-2 -5.95 -3.25 -4.8 Q-3.7 -4.05 -3.7 -3.05 -3.7 -2 -3.25 -1.2 -2.8 -0.45 -2 -0.05 L-0.35 0.4 1.3 -0.05 2.5 -1.25 Q3 -2 3 -3.05"/>
    </g>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <filter id="18t4a8dd8-2">
      <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <feFuncA type="linear" intercept="0" slope="1"/>
        <feFuncR type="linear" intercept="1" slope="0"/>
        <feFuncG type="linear" intercept="0" slope="1"/>
        <feFuncB type="linear" intercept="1" slope="0"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
    <g transform="matrix(2 0 0 2 50 20)" filter="url(#18t4a8dd8-2)">
```

etc.